# Studies on the application of "Red Flag Laws" in the US

Tags: united-states, judiciary, guns, reference-request

I'm looking for objective studies describing how red flag gun laws involving Extreme Risk Protection Orders (ERPOs) are being used in those U.S. states that have implemented them.   I'd like to see statistics addressing whether such orders are based on petitions from family vs. law enforcement, the percentage of petitions granted (ex-parte or otherwise), and what follow-up hearings/cases are being used.

While such laws clearly raise 2nd amendment concerns for some, I'm more interested in the issue of due process (fifth amendment) protections and the review and transparency of decisions of individual judges who issue ERPOs by higher-level courts.

Comment: Can the downvoters please explain to me why this was downvoted?

Comment: These laws are very new. I doubt that there are any good studies that have been done yet.

Comment: In Washington State, where I live, the red flag law (RCW 7.94) passed in 2017, and the first ERPO was [granted in 2018](https://truthinmedia.com/seattle-police-first-erpo-gun-seizure/), but there is apparently no system that tracks how many ERPOs are issued.